# Postgis vector tiles clustering in open layers

Tags: openlayers, postgis

I am trying to cluster the vector tiles provided by postgis in openlayers map. How can this be performed? Any guide will be a help for me.

Comment: OpenLayers clustering can only be done on a Vector source.  You would need to load your Vector Tiles into a vector source https://stackoverflow.com/a/55171290/10118270

Answer (score 0):

You can also cluster data at backend using  [postgis's clustering functions](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/reference.html#Clustering_Functions) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).